# How to Catch up On Tests for Rails Site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, automated-tests, integration-testing

I learned Rails to create a website and the basic version is up and running. Unfortunately, I only wrote a couple of tests for my code. What should I do now to get test coverage for my code? It will be difficult to go back now and write tests for all my previous code. Would it make sense to use a recording tool like Selenium to visit the sites and record tests? Is there a specific recording tool for Rails?

(In short, how can one catch up to get test coverage on code that doesn't have enough tests?)

Answer (score 1):

First, quantitatively measure your test coverage with a tool like [rcov](https://github.com/relevance/rcov).

You're right that integration tests will provide more coverage, so they are the right choice for your goal.  However, they provide less meaningful feedback when they fail, so you'll want to augment or replace them with more isolated tests in the future.

I expect that recording tests will result in a test whose source is hard for humans to read.  So, you might want to consider [capybara-webkit](https://github.com/relevance/rcov) instead (but [don't use capybara 2.1 yet](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/505)).

Finally, because your current testbase is small, you have an opportunity to consider [rspec](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec) or [shoulda-context](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-context).

Answer (score 0):

Truth is, you're going to just have to go back and right all the tests.

First of, no kind of "recording" tool would help with the unit and controller tests.

Second, if you did use something to "record" feature/integration tests, what exactly would you be testing? If you aren't specific to what functionally you expect to be there, how can you be sure your app is even doing now what it's supposed to be doing?

Comment: Until now I've been checking things manually to see if it works. So I can do one more check and automatically record what happens. (I can then keep the important information that it shows.) Then in the future if something breaks, it will automatically show up when the tests run.  That sounds much easier then writing tests for everything now.

Comment: Yeah, well "easier" shouldn't be your goal.  Think of it this way, the only test you can record right now is "Application works good".  And when something "breaks", all that means is that the behavior is different than it is now.  But, what is different?  And is that difference good or bad?  You really need to just grit your teeth and write tests like "Admins can see these buttons", "Regular users cannot see these buttons", "Submitting form with no errors creates a new user", "Forgetting email causes validation error", etc.  If you aren't willing to do that, no need to write any tests at all.